# Add rule to CSS class, then save stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I open page 1.html, I use javascript to add a background image to the page body. It looks like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.example.com/image.jpg)";
```

The script inserts the background image in the CSS body class.

My question. **Using vanilla JS, how cand I save this change to the CSS file** http://www.example.com/my_css.css ? So that when I open page 2.html, the body class already has the background image added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under a typical set up, you cannot modify the CSS file (it lives on the server, is accessible to all users, and there is no default way (aka Massive Security Hole) for browsers to overwrite files on the server).

Typically, for this type of problem, you would set a cookie on page 1 and then read it back on page 2 and, using the data in it, determine that you need to set a different background image.

You could also store the information elsewhere, such as in local storage.

If you needed the change of background image to be visible for all users, then you would need to inform the server of this (typically, you would use Ajax for this) and have server side code keep track of the information and share it between users (e.g. by storing the status in a database and then setting a class on the body element when the HTML was generated).